# Find $n$ such that $(m-1)(m+3)(m-4)(m-8)+n$ is a perfect square for all $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $n$ such that $(m-1)(m+3)(m-4)(m-8)+n$ is a perfect square for all $m$

---

I am thinking of starting like this

$(m-1)(m+3)(m-4)(m-8)+n = k^2 \implies (m-1)(m+3)(m-4)(m-8) = k^2-n$

Honestly somewhat scared of expanding the products on left hand side. Any hints/help on the next step ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to do $(m-1)(m+3)(m-4)(m-8)=\underbrace{(m-1)(m-4)}\underbrace{(m+3)(m-8)}$ since $-1-4=-5=3-8$ giving same coefficient of m:

---

$$(m-1)(m+3)(m-4)(m-8)+n=(m^2-5m+4)(m^2-5m-24)+n\stackrel{y=m^2-5m+4}=y(y-28)+n=y^2-28y+n=(y-14)^2+n-14^2\implies n=14^2=196$$

Comment: Can you explain why you made $(y-14)^2 + n - 14^2 = 0$, as well as assuming $y = 14$? Sorry if this is obvious but I would like to completely understand your proof!

Comment: @InsigMath no, i made $(y-14)^2+n-14^2=k^2$ and letting $k=y-14$ you get $n=14^2$

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense! Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As $-1-4=-8+3,$

$$(m-1)(m-4)(m+3)(m-8)$$

$$=(\underbrace{m^2-5m}+4)(\underbrace{m^2-5m}-24)$$

$$=(\underbrace{m^2-5m})^2-20(\underbrace{m^2-5m})-96$$

$$=\{(\underbrace{m^2-5m})-10\}^2-96-100$$